# What is "standardize" in "h2o.deeplearning" options?

Tags: r, h2o, standardized

Manual says "Logical. If enabled, automatically standardize the data. If disabled, the user must provide properly scaled input data."

I tried learning with iris data.

### R source code

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

xx <- data.frame(c(1:10), c(1:10) * 10, c(1:10) * 100)

iris.hex <- as.h2o(xx)
bb <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:2, y = 3, training_frame = iris.hex, standardize = TRUE, 
                   activation = "Rectifier", hidden = c(10, 10), export_weights_and_biases = TRUE)

predictions <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(bb, iris.hex))

weights_01 <- as.matrix(h2o.weights(bb, matrix_id = 1))
weights_02 <- as.matrix(h2o.weights(bb, matrix_id = 2))
weights_03 <- as.matrix(h2o.weights(bb, matrix_id = 3))

biases_01 <- as.matrix(h2o.biases(bb, vector_id = 1))
biases_02 <- as.matrix(h2o.biases(bb, vector_id = 2))
biases_03 <- as.matrix(h2o.biases(bb, vector_id = 3))

xx_temp <- xx ## This step standardizes my data
for (i in 1:3){
  xx_temp[ , i] <- xx_temp[ , i] / max(xx_temp[ , i])
}

result_mat <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 1)
for (j in 1:10){
  asdf <- as.matrix(xx_temp[j, 1:2])
  asdf <- weights_01 %*% t(asdf) + biases_01
  asdf[asdf < 0] <- 0

  asdf <- weights_02 %*% (asdf) + biases_02
  asdf[asdf < 0] <- 0

  asdf <- weights_03 %*% (asdf) + biases_03
  result_mat[j, 1] <- asdf
}
result_mat

cbind(predictions[1:10, 1], result_mat) ## << What is differences of two data
```

My question is how can I calculate 'result mat' as 'predictions' ??

Answer (score 0):

`standardize()` is same as `scale()` of R. In statistical modeling you don't want effect of one variable to very heavy as compare to another variable just because of their scales. For example think age and salary in one model. Human age you expect to get in range 0-100 while salary  can go $20000-big CEOs salary. So in numerical munging in models $20000 will be very big and hence very dominating as compare to age say 20. To bring both into same level and to make these variables equally effective it is suggested to use `standardize()`.